# Updating access db using SQL in C# - DATE issue

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

Im a n00b with c#, been using vba for a while and stepping up.

i have this code:

```
OleDbCommand sqlcom = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE tblpack SET packeduser = 1 AND packeddate ='" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "' WHERE packid = " + packid, con);
```

I know it isnt parametized, that will be my next step, im really just learning basics right now.

My issue is without date section, the update sql works fine.

WITH the date section, there is no error but the sql doesnt end up firing.

I have stopped at the execute non query and the sql looks fine...
my date field in Access is set blank, but i have tried "general date" with no luck either.

Any ideas!?/

UPDATE:
Apologies you are 100% correct i shouldn't be skimping on security even for learning.
I have rewritten as parametized and it is working.
I believe my issues with the AND instead of , in the SQL (it was 3am).
Datetime.now actually works to Access, instead of having to convert to string.  Im not sure why this worked.. i have read so much about needing to convert!

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString);

                        string strpacked = "UPDATE tblpack SET packeduser = 1, packeddate = ? WHERE packid = ?";

                        OleDbDataAdapter dataadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

                        OleDbCommand sqlcom = new OleDbCommand(strpacked, con);

                        sqlcom.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Date, 5).Value = DateTime.Now;
                        sqlcom.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer, 5).Value = packid;

                        dataadapter.SelectCommand = sqlcom;

                        con.Open();

                        sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        row.Cells["clnpackeduser"].Value = "GA";
                        con.Close();
```

Comment: Pass the value in as a parameter rather than munging the SQL string with a string parameter.

Comment: Using parameters should be [your first step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types).

Comment: *"I know it isnt parametized ... im really just learning basics right now."* - Using parameterized queries *is* one of the basics. Why waste time fighting with a problem related to "doing it wrong" when you can just go ahead and "do it right"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Jet (MS Access database engine) date format is: `#MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss#`.
Thus you must change your code like this:

```
OleDbCommand sqlcom = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE tblpack SET packeduser = 1, packeddate =" + DateTime.Now.ToString("#MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss#") + " WHERE packid = " + packid, con);
```

Be careful, I have removed `'` from example.

In your case MS Jet can't parse date string and leaves date is blank.

UPDATE:

You must use `,` instead `AND` in SET clause.

Comment: Have in mind, that **/** and **:** is the date and time separator, not a slash or colon, and hours must be 24, and the date sequence should be ISO, thus: `DateTime.Now.ToString("#yyyy'/'MM'/'dd HH':'mm':'ss#")`.